# Passing data from one tab to another using ActionBar.TabListener

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have `mainactivity` which contains two tabs and has the following code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private class MyTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener
    {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mFrag;

        public MyTabListener( Activity activity, String fragName )
        {
            mActivity = activity;
            mFrag = fragName;
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabSelected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate( mActivity, mFrag );
            ft.add( android.R.id.content, mFragment );
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected( Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft )
        {
            ft.remove( mFragment );
            mFragment = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
        ab.setNavigationMode( ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS );

        Tab tab = ab.newTab()
                .setText( "Current Trip" )
                .setTabListener( 
                        new MyTabListener( this, current.class.getName() ) );
        ab.addTab( tab );

        tab = ab.newTab()
                .setText( "Display Result" )
                .setTabListener( 
                        new MyTabListener( this, display.class.getName() ) );
        ab.addTab( tab );


        File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/tc");
        boolean success = true;
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Does Not Exist, Create It", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            success = folder.mkdir();
        }
        if (success) {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Directory Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Failed - Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

How do I pass data of a edittext from `current.class` to be shown and also used in `display.class` for calculation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you use shared prefs e.g.

```
this is the frag that "writes":
private SharedPreferences prefs;  // shared preferences 
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("spa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putString("someId", "something");  //or you can use putInt, putBoolean ... 
editor.commit();

this is the frag the "reads"
prefs = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("spa", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String someId=prefs.getString("someId",someId);
```

Alternatively you could call the a method in one fragment from the other (it is best to do this via the mainactivity rather than directly).

```
 from frag 1:
((activity)getActivity()).somemethod();

 in activity:

 fragment2 fragment = (fragment2) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment2");
 fragment.somemethod();
```

Comment: An example of Shared Prefs? Will it go in the MainActivity? How do I clear it out?

Comment: For your first suggestion, which code am I putting on tab one class and which code in tab two class?

Comment: I've added in some examples now. I've sketched out the bare bones of this - but it is better if you now do a bit of research and turn this into a solution.

Comment: I did research and found out about SharePreference. Just not sure how to implement it in my app.

Comment: Oh - my code is tried and tested and close to what you want. Just copy and paste and change the putString to suit. I will post the corresponding getString in a couple of mins ...

Comment: Updated - it is easy to use and easy to debug - just start with something simple ...

Comment: Thanks, It makes more sense now. One issue I have after adding you code in the reading fragment for this line: `String someId=prefs.getString("someId",someId);` I get an error: `The local variable someId may not have been initialized`

Comment: I fixed it, i removed someId and used "" and it worked! Thanks.

Comment: Yes - that's fine - that value simply specifies the value to be used if the variable does not exist in shared prefs. Shared prefs is a good method for communicating between activities and fragments and I find it to be very reliable and very useful.

Comment: Would you happen to know why the values I entered in Fragment #1 disappears once it goes to Fragment #2? Is it because, although they are two tabs, they are two separate activities? How would I ensure they stay intact even after switching tab unless the user deletes it?

Comment: Yes - almost certainly it is because you are adding and removing fragments - so you are creating new instances of your fragments each time. Think about using attach and detach instead - they are just as easy to use and when you attach you get back the same instance you were using previously. Well done for getting this stuff working by the way !

Comment: Oh ... I should say ... you add it if it is null (first time) in. Then you detach it when you unselect and attach it when you select. You will find sample code around for this type of thing if you Google or open a new Question. It's not too difficult to get working.

Comment: Unfortunately the method, although it works like a charm, is not suitable only because I have fragments using different activities and using the `append()` does not work

Comment: append ? do you mean attach and detach fragments  ?